# python win32gui HWD_TOPMOST is not defined

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

i want to set my window on the top:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE)
```

but, it fails:

> NameError: global name ‘`HWND_TOP`‘ is not defined

is `HWND_TOP` need define?
i can’t find `HWND_TOP` value from help doc PyWin32.chm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google... try google - `python win32 HWND_TOP`. [First result](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/85989/win32gui.SetWindowPos) looks like the constant is defined in module `win32con`. Please import it and retry.

Comment: As far as the constants are concerned, they belong to 'win32con' module, so you must import this model and then: 

   `wg.SetWindowPos(hwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW | wc.SWP_NOMOVE)`

However, there's another weird error that occurs: **"pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetWindowPos', 'No error message is available')"**  !!  In these "stuborn" cases I usually choose to totally disregard these functions!